# Thunderbird: Removing Mail Account

Tags: thunderbird

I have a general question concerning Thunderbird in Ubuntu 18.04: If I remove my mail account from Thunderbird, but had IMAP configured, will all my mails be lost?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doubtful. Unless you also deleted all the emails before hand,

Comment: Ähm, you broke off your sentence in the middle.

Comment: No, it was complete. Poor eyesight so hit , instead of .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. IMAP treats the server as the primary data store, so all your messages will remain on the server.

POP, on the other hand, treats the client (i.e. Thunderbird) as the primary data store, so messages would be deleted in that case.

This is part of the protocols, so your OS, client (Thunderbird), and mail provider (posteo) are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have a **posteo**-account and so I just wrote the support team an email. They told me that the emails wouldn't be deleted if **IMAP** was used.

(Note that if you set up a posteo-account, it is probably better to just delete your old mail account, just as I did.)